# jQuery : Getting the parent content

Tags: jquery, dom

I have the following DOM structure :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="column-1">
                This is the column one text
            </div>
            <div id="column-2">
                <div id="part-1">
                    Part one
                </div>
                <div id="part-2">
                    Part two
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert($(this).parent().html());
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div id="part-3">
                    Part three
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </body>
</html>
```

What I want is to get the content of the parent (`<div id="part-2">`).

The problem is a the instruction : `alert($(this).parent().html())`.

Why it is returning null ?

(PS: I know I can reach the `<div id="part-2">` with `$("#part-2").html()`, but the parent id can change dynamically this is why I want to get that parent with the `$(this).parent().html()` instruction)

Comment: in your case `this` refers to `window`.

Comment: You haven't specified what `$(this)` is.

Comment: @AlexThomas @AndresAL Why it is not taking the `script` tag as the current element ?

Comment: because that's not how javascript works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `$(this)` doesn't mean anything in a random piece of javascript.   You aren't giving it a scope.  For example:

```
$( 'button' ).click( function() { alert( $(this).parent().html() ); } );
```

In that code, `$(this)` refers to the button.  You need to bind some event to the div, so that you can use `$(this).parent()`;

Another way to think about it is, the placement of the javascript relative to the HTML elements is irrelevant when it comes to objects such as `$(this)`;

For your code, you could add this:

```
$( 'div.column-2 div' ).click( function() { alert( $(this).html() ); } );
```

That will alert the HTML of the div you click on, and it will work with all three in your example (part-1, part-2 and part-3)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to show previous sibling and not the parent...try with this:

```
$("#part-2").prev().html()
```

Comment: OK, if the ID can be changed, you need to find the other logic to find relevant div...for example does your div always even or always odd? Do you have an ability to set class to div that you need?

Answer (score 0):

It's returning nil because the DOM is not complete, i.e. when the JS is run the div "part-2" is not closed so it can't get the HTML, never mind the parent HTML, if you put it in a button, then it should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/E9eA8/